# Eslint plugin to detect accessibility problems of react components written with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, styled-components

How to detect accessibility problems of react components written with styled-components?

For react components, there is a nice eslint plugin called [eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y) that can be applied to detect accessibility problems of react components.

But if you use [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) library to write react components, then this plugin does not seem to find the accessibility problems.
Is there a similar eslint plugin for styled-components? Or could I somehow configure the eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y to find errors also from styled components? I see there is an open issue about the subject here: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/466

Reading that Im still not sure how to achieve this, any help?